# Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator - Procedure Error Correction

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, type-conversion, error-correction

I am using SQL Server - 2005...

```
ALTER Proc [dbo].[ExamResult] (@Course_Id varchar(100), @Semester varchar(10))
as
begin
    declare @subjname varchar(100)  
    declare @subjects varchar(7000)  
    declare @subjectsselection varchar(7000)  
    declare @SumSelection varchar(7000)  
    declare @NoOfSubjects int
    set @NoOfSubjects = 0

    set @subjects = ''  
    set @subjectsselection = '' 
    set @SumSelection = ''

    DECLARE subject_cursor CURSOR  
    FOR SELECT distinct Subject_Name FROM Exam_Result where course_id = @Course_Id And Semester = @Semester 

    OPEN subject_cursor  

    FETCH NEXT FROM subject_cursor  
    INTO @subjname  

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
    BEGIN  
        set @subjects = @subjects + '[' + @subjname + '],'  
        set @subjectsselection = @subjectsselection + 'Sum(Isnull([' + @subjname + '],0)) As [' + @subjname + '],' 
        set @SumSelection = @SumSelection + 'Sum(Isnull([' + @subjname + '],0))+' 

        set @NoOfSubjects = @NoOfSubjects + 1

        FETCH NEXT FROM subject_cursor  
        INTO @subjname  
    End  
    CLOSE subject_cursor;  
    DEALLOCATE subject_cursor;  

    select @subjects = LEFT(@subjects, LEN(@subjects) - 1)  
    select @subjectsselection = LEFT(@subjectsselection, LEN(@subjectsselection) - 1)  
    select @SumSelection = LEFT(@SumSelection, LEN(@SumSelection) - 1)  

    print @subjects  
    print @subjectsselection  
    print @SumSelection

    declare @query nvarchar(4000)  

    set @query = 'select S.Enroll_Number, pvt.Student_Name, pvt.Course_Id, pvt.Semester, ' + @subjectsselection + ',' 
    set @query = @query + 'Exam_Type,' + @SumSelection + ' As Grand_Total, '
    set @query = @query + '(' + @SumSelection + ')' + '/' + convert(varchar(10),@NoOfSubjects) + ' As Avg'
    set @query = @query + ' From '  
    set @query = @query + '(select Enroll_Number, Student_Name, Course_Id, Semester, Subject_Name, MarksObtained, Exam_Type from Exam_Result ) ps '  
    set @query = @query + ' pivot(sum(MarksObtained) for Subject_Name in (' + @subjects + ')) as pvt'  
    set @query = @query + ' inner join Stud_Info S on S.Enroll_Number = pvt.Enroll_Number '
    set @query = @query + ' where pvt.Course_Id = ''' + @Course_Id + ''' and pvt.Semester = ''' + @Semester + ''''
    set @query = @query + ' group by S.Enroll_Number, pvt.Student_Name, pvt.Course_Id, pvt.Semester, Exam_Type'
    print @query
    exec sp_executesql @query  
end
```

**Exam_Result table**:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Exam_Result](
    [Result_Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Enroll_Number] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Student_Name] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Course_Id] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Semester] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Subject_Id] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Subject_Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [MarksObtained] [Varchar](10) NULL,
    [Exam_Type] [varchar](50) NULL)
```

**Sample data query**...

```
INSERT into Exam_Result VALUES('11147','Mr.Mack28','CIV','1','PS1','ps1','60','Final')
INSERT into Exam_Result VALUES('11147','Mr.Mack28','CIV','3','PS1','ps1','70','Final')
INSERT into Exam_Result VALUES('11147','Mr.Mack28','CIV','3','PS1','ps1','80','Final')
INSERT into Exam_Result VALUES('11147','Mr.Mack28','CIV','3','PS1','ps1','20','Internal')
INSERT into Exam_Result VALUES('11147','Mr.Mack28','CIV','3','PS1','ps1','22','Internal')
```

**Student_Info table**: I just use for retrieved **Student_Information** like Enroll_Number...

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Stud_Info](
    [Enroll_Number] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [Student_Name] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [Course_Type] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [Course_Id] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [Semester] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [Password] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [Gender] [varchar](6) NULL,
    [City] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [Mobile_Number] [varchar](10) NULL)
```

It gives me error like this...

> Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator.

**Rahul**: as per you answer I updated like this but it still gives error......

```
set @query = @query + ' pivot(sum(cast(MarksObtained as int)) for Subject_Name in (' + @subjects + ')) as pvt'
```

I think it gives error because I am using the `MarksObtained` column (`as varchar(10)`)...plz give me a suggestion how I can convert `varchar` to `int` so that summation of total `MarksObtained` can be done.

Comment: If the column contains integer values, why did you declare it as VARCHAR?

Comment: at last time v have ordered to mark it as varchar in case of any student is absent in that subject then we have to insert as ABS...dats way i want to convert it

Comment: Then convert it **in the application**. Don't store it in the database.

Comment: oded - is it possible ?? let me try...

Answer (score 4):

You can convert like this way:

```
SUM (CONVERT(int,<your varchar column>))
```

This will work if your varchar column actually holds numeric value. Otherwise, you can try casting it using `cast` function like:

```
sum(cast(varchar_column as int))
```

**EDIT:**

Created a sample table with just 2 column (name and marksobtained), both of type `varchar(10)` and inserted some data to it. So that my `select *` looks like

```
name            marksobtained
Mr. Anil             30
Mr. sunil            70
Mr. patel            70
```

Summed the marks like

```
select SUM(cast(marksobtained as int)) as 'totalmarksobtained' from sampletab
```

Which returned `170`.

What values does `@subjects` have? Post some sample.

Comment: rahul - thanks for your instant reply but both still not working for me...i have updated my question..u can see it

Comment: Mack, please share some sample data for `MarksObtained` column. Will try it once and let you know.

Comment: Mack, sorry for delay in response. I tried and it worked. See my edit.

Comment: Rahul - its ok. thanks for giving me your important time... i'm unable to find your edit !!! plz tell me...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10919/discussion-between-mack28-and-rahul)

Comment: Rahul - ok... thanks but its not working in my cursor which i have described above ?? is there anything going wrong in my cursor / **sum** syntax....

Answer (score 0):

you can use "cast" in your query

example:

```
select sum(cast(Enter_your_field_name as int)) from Table_name
```

Hope it works for you.